# cursor moves to new generated textbox in angualarjs

Tags: angularjs

I have form with modal, When i click enter or add email button it generates the new text box but cursor will not move into that text box.

But i need when i click enter or add email button, then cursor automatically should move to the newly generated text box.

My html code

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <li ng-repeat="item in items " ng-form="subForm">
              <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="item.email" required ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"  ng-enter="addOrRemove($index,item.email)"/>
              <span ng-show="subForm.name.$error.required" style="color: red">Email required</span>
              <span ng-show="subForm.name.$invalid" ng-hide="subForm.name.$error.required" style="color: red">Invalid email</span>
              <button ng-disabled="subForm.name.$invalid || subFform.name.$dirty" ng-click="addOrRemove($index,item.email)" >{{item.value}}</button>
               expression: {{subForm.name.$invalid}}
          </li>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
  </script>
```

My javascript code

```
$scope.addOrRemove = function(indexSelected,rcvEmail)
{//alert($rootScope.email1);

    if(!rcvEmail)
    {
        return
    }
    console.log("just check email",rcvEmail);
    console.log("length of the object",$scope.items.length);
    event.preventDefault();
    if($scope.items[indexSelected].state == 1)
    {
        //console.log($scope.items[indexSelected].state);
        $scope.items[indexSelected].value = "Remove email";
        $scope.items[indexSelected].state = "0";
        $scope.items[indexSelected].email = rcvEmail;
        $scope.items.push({value: "Add email", state: "1"});
    }
    else
    {
        //console.log($scope.items[indexSelected].state);
        //$scope.items.push({value: "Remove email", state: "1"});
        $scope.items.splice(indexSelected, 1);
    }

};
```

[see the code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/L1SD59951vKya7IBq7RV?p=preview)

Comment: Try to add `ng-init="myinputfocus = true" focus="myinputfocus"` to your `<input>` element. And then whenever you need to focus this field again just set `myinputfocus = true`;

Comment: can you send an example link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to focus an input you have to create custom directive.

```
.directive('focus', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link:     function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.focus, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if(newValue) {
                    element[0].focus();
                }
            });
            element.bind("blur", function(e) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.focus + "=false");
                }, 0);
            });
            element.bind("focus", function(e) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.focus + "=true");
                }, 0);
            })
        }
    }
})
```

And then you can use it in the input.

```
<input type="text" ng-init="inp_focus = true" focus="inp_focus" />
```

Please check this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Serhioromano/bu2k2cb7/

Comment: When i press  add email button then a new text box will be generated but cursor will not move into that newly generated textbox..

Comment: How do you generate that textbox? Is it partial template or simply HTML text or directive? Can you create an example?

Comment: Already i mentioned a link in plunker above...    http://plnkr.co/edit/L1SD59951vKya7IBq7RV?p=preview

Comment: There is something wrong with your example I could not fix it. I created new plnkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/GvbHbddFO99jhDI6wwL4?p=preview

Comment: For thank you there is up arrow on the left of the comment or post.